# Why do you get 50g for last hitting the nexus?

Tags: league-of-legends

Several times now, I happen to be the one who last hits and finishes an enemy nexus. In these cases, I got 50g from doing so. I verified that I do not get that extra if I do not last hit the nexus. What is the point of this gold? Killing the nexus means you already won the game so what is the point? Is there some sort of inside joke or background story behind this or is this just a "bug" that Riot haven't gotten around to fixing yet because it is low impact.

Comment: Questions about ["Why did they design it that way?"](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2429/why-did-they-design-it-that-way-anyway-and-why-do-we-allow-or-disallow-thes) are off topic.

Comment: Try asking something more like "Does the 50g received from last-hitting a Nexus affect gameplay/stats?"

Comment: I don't understand... why the additional downvotes after it's already closed...

Comment: @jay I had the same problem (people downvoting my closed question), some people are just negative and want to share their negativity I suppose. The advice I recieved and will pass on is to vote to delete your question as soon as possible.

Comment: @Ender: I agree. The point of downvotes are to show that a question isn't great quality. To downvote a question that has already been closed is kinda spiteful at that point. Plus, this type of question isn't explicitly off-topic according to the FAQ and is only considered off-topic from a meta post. I'm sorry if I didn't read through all the meta questions...

Answer (score 3):

There are many speculations as to why riot gives 50 gold for killing the Nexus.

1. Some say that it is so that the player knows who last hit it.
2. Some people say that is it because buildings are coded to reward gold and because the nexus is technically a building it still rewards gold. It would probably be a pain to make that exception in the code when it really doesn't matter.
3. Some say it is just so you can all go out for a round of drinks after the win with the bros.
4. Personally, I think Riot is just trolling us.

**The clear cut answer is theres nothing coming from Riot stating why they reward the gold.**

Answer (score 2):

Lots of players consider their acquired gold count for the round an important statistic on how well they did that round.  Just because the round's over, doesn't mean that it shouldn't reward the person who got last hit